# HttpListener in form application

Tags: c#

I have simple HttpListener console application below. I would like to make nice Form application, but how to deal with `while (true)` cycle in order to let window brief?

```
   private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // URI prefixes are required,
        var prefixes = new List<string>() { "http://*:1234/" };

        // Create a listener.
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        // Add the prefixes.
        foreach (string s in prefixes)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
        }
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        while (true)
        {
            // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request.
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

            //HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

            if (context.Request.HttpMethod.ToLower().ToString() == "get")
            {


            }
            else if (context.Request.HttpMethod.ToLower().ToString() == "post")
            {

            }



        }
        listener.Stop();

    }
```

Comment: You need encapsulate the loop in background thread. From the background thread, you can use the thread synchronization context to update the UI.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is what you need to research

Comment: might i suggest using kestrel - asp.net core's web server - it is much better than http listener